# adb push very slow from virtualbox ubuntu to android device

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb, virtualbox

Now I am developing some codes in virtualbox ubuntu machine, and the host machine is win7. When the codes are ready, I put the library to the device using the following command `adb push abc.so /data/local/tmp/myabcfolder`. However, the speed of transferring data is so slow that the shell almost stops. If I push files of small volumes to the device, it seems fine. Any ideas on how I can put the relatively large library to the device? Thanks.

ps: When transferring the data to the device, it reaches a certain mount of data very quickly（393216）, and then stops as the following picture shows:

[image]

Comment: 4Mb is not that big of a file and it should not take more than couple of seconds to upload it. I would suggest configuring `PCI pass-through` for one of your USB controllers in `virtualbox` settings. You won't be able to use any devices connected to that controller in your host system but it will ensure the best possible USB performance inside the VM.

Comment: @Alex P - can you explain how to set PCI pass-through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find the reason: it is because when the Android device is attached, it does not use USB 2.0 protocol. In virtualbox, there is a place to set this option:

[image]

But in order to enable USB 2.0, you have to install virtualbox extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution here will be to use shared drive:
Mount your real folder to your VBox and it will be much more faster than copying with `adb`.
You can find [more information here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825169/android-virtualbox-shared-folders)