# Virtualbox Shared Folder With using kivy

Tags: virtualbox, kivy, shared-directory

Ive been trying to use ubuntu on virtualbox to make APK from my Android program that I wrote with kivy.

But it just doesn't work. VM doesn't recognize shared folder. I've tried everything like guest-additions and I've check every article/Q-A about this subject and I'm about to go mad.

Is there any other way to make APK in windows other than using a VM. Please inform me, I've got my exams soon and I don't want to get hang to this subject anymore. I'm using windows 10. Thank you for your helps.

Comment: Have you tried just not using a shared folder?

Comment: If you only want to deploy to a device, go for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27613390/5994041) answer and work with usb (it's more useful even for `adb` and `logcat`). However, I was able to manage shared folders, yet I don't have a clue how. I'm pretty sure there was another package needed, not only guestadditions. Try maybe [ubuntu docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders)?